# Person's and the use of their

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions

Here's part of a sentence:

> a person's self image and their behavior...

Is it correct to use *their* in that situation? Or should it be *his* or *her*?
This is from an older essay from university, so the grammar has to be okay.

Comment: "so the grammar has to okay" Do you mean. This is an essay from university so you think the grammar is correct, or that you need to make sure the grammar is correct.

Comment: Gender-neutral "their" is fine

Answer (score -3):

In formal writing, you must use "his or her" when referring to a singular noun. "Their" must refer to a plural noun.

Comment: To make this sentence correct, you could write "A person's self image and behavior ..." or "A person's self image and his or her behavior ..." To know which one is better, I would need context.